# How to activate Substrate GRANDPA finalization?

Tags: blockchain, parity, substrate

I want to start a chain with Babe/Grandpa consensus. I'm able to start block production using `Toolbox->RPC->author->insertKey()` in UI. But I don't know how to start block finalization.

I've tried setting grandpa keys the same way I sat babe keys in `Toolbox->RPC->author->insertKey()`:

- keyType: `gran`
- suri: `//Alice`
- publicKey: `0x88dc3417d5058ec4b4503e0c12ea1a0a89be200fe98922423d4334014fa6b0ee` (I also tried `sr25519` version `0xd43593c715fdd31c61141abd04a99fd6822c8558854ccde39a5684e7a56da27d`)

And it didn't help.

Here you can see that block number increments properly while the finalized counter remains #0:

```
2020-01-16 15:03:19 Idle (1 peers), best: #101 (0x56ce…7c6a), finalized #0 (0x885c…85d7), ⬇ 0 ⬆ 0
2020-01-16 15:03:21 Imported #102 (0xe984…2776)
2020-01-16 15:03:24 Idle (1 peers), best: #102 (0xe984…2776), finalized #0 (0x885c…85d7), ⬇ 0.1kiB/s ⬆ 10 B/s
2020-01-16 15:03:27 Starting consensus session on top of parent 0xe98487a704c4fb20239df06ba4e8dda9e57c3fa1813b97819c16311c4ac92776
2020-01-16 15:03:29 Idle (1 peers), best: #102 (0xe984…2776), finalized #0 (0x885c…85d7), ⬇ 72 B/s ⬆ 76 B/s
2020-01-16 15:03:31 Imported #103 (0xc3ef…1438)
2020-01-16 15:03:34 Idle (1 peers), best: #103 (0xc3ef…1438), finalized #0 (0x885c…85d7), ⬇ 0.1kiB/s ⬆ 10 B/s
```

Answer (score 2):

There is a good tutorial to [Start a network with Substrate](https://substrate.dev/docs/en/next/tutorials/start-a-private-network/) which covers almost the exact topics you're looking for with one small exception that it uses Aura for block production rather than Babe.

If you want to use the well-known Alice, Bob, etc accounts as validators, the easiest way to get their keys into the keystore is to supply the `--alice` flag when starting the node. This approach is covered in [step 2](https://substrate.dev/docs/en/next/tutorials/start-a-private-network/alicebob) of the tutorial. From `substrate --help`:

> --alice
>       Shortcut for `--name Alice --validator` with session keys for `Alice` added to keystore.

If you want to use your own self-generated keys, you will have to make the RPC calls as you're describing. This process is covered at the [end of step 4](https://substrate.dev/docs/en/next/tutorials/start-a-private-network/customchain#adding-keys-to-keystore) in the tutorial.

It *is* possible to insert the well-know Alice key via the RPC call as you attempted. Here are two reasons that you may not have finalized blocks when you attempted this approach.

- GRANDPA requires 2/3 of validators to be casting finality votes to finalize anything ([research](https://research.web3.foundation/en/latest/polkadot/GRANDPA.html)). If you have other validators in your chain specification, nothing will get finalized until you've inserted the proper keys into at least 2/3 of the validating nodes.
- You *may* need to supply the full [dev phrase](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/6e0a4877afbe2309e106b84333bb70200531b604/primitives/core/src/crypto.rs#L43) when inserting the keys rather than just `//Alice`.

Comment: I went through the tutorial with `aura` and `substrate-node-template` repo. The same problem, submitting 2 grandpa keys of 2 total via RPC call doesn't start finalization, though, specifying `--alice` and `--bob` does. Is it possible to debug this process somehow?

Comment: Have you made sure to insert one key into each node? When you make RPC calls from the UI you're making them to a specific node. It won't work if you insert both keys into a single node. So you'll have to connect UI to alice's node, insert alice's keys, connect ui to bob's node, insert bob's keys.

Comment: I'm executing these 4 following commands in order to start a `local_testnet` chain template with `//Alice` and `//Bob` as 2 validators. Are they correct?
https://gist.github.com/chebykin/4dbe8f5c43926b8424e87ed0a16ae6a4

Comment: I've found a temporary solution. Restarting the nodes after injecting keys via RPC starts finalization. Probably a bug with Substrate.